# Parse XML to a different format with SAX

Tags: java, xml, parsing, sax

I have a huge problem with parsing an XML file to a different format.
I'm trying to get all the related data like stated in this link: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/
(I searched stackoverflow before and found this link)

I use the interface XMLReader to parse and the XML Serializer for the output.

I just need to convert my XML with a DTD to another XML with a different DTD. The difference is that, instead of elements from my source XML, most of the children are now attributes in the target XML. There are no new elements, only a different arrangement.

Has anyone an idea how to deal with the problem with a SAX parser?

Answer (score 2):

You can use XMLFilters for that. See [Elliotte Rusty Harold's book](http://cafeconleche.org/books/xmljava/chapters/ch08.html) for explanation and examples:

> The basic idea of filters is that an XMLReader, instead of receiving
>   XML text directly from a file, socket, or other source, receives
>   already parsed events from another XMLReader. It can change these
>   events before passing them along to the client application through the
>   usual methods of ContentHandler and the other callback interfaces. For
>   example, it can add a unique ID attribute to every element or delete
>   all elements in the SVG namespace from the input stream.

BTW the mkyong tutorial glosses over how the characters method works, that tends to bite a lot of people when they find their element data getting truncated. There's [a better tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html) on Oracle's site.